# Move div horizontal inside a div only when div is on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to move a div inside another div when scrolling down. I want the div to only move side to side only when the div is on screen and only to move from one side to another inside the ".boatFlex2" boundaries. (that the blue part..)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $horizontal = $('#horizontal');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
            d = $(document).height(),
            c = $(this).height();

        scrollPercent = (s / (d - c));

        var position = (scrollPercent * ($(document).width() - $horizontal.width()));
        
        $horizontal.css({
            'left': position
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.section{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative:
}

.boatFlex1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    background-color: green;
    justify-content:center;
    align-content: center;
    
}

.boatFlex2{
    width: 47%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #090080;
}

#horizontal {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    background: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="section">
</div>
<div id="boatFlex1" class="boatFlex1">
    <div id="boatFlex2" class="boatFlex2">
        <div id="horizontal">test</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section">
</div>
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xofsu2gc/)

Answer (score 0):

Compute the new position using:

```
var position = (scrollPercent * ($horizontal.position().left + $horizontal.width()));
```

and set **#horizontal** position to relative

```js
var $horizontal = $('#horizontal');

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
            d = $(document).height(),
            c = $(this).height();

    scrollPercent = (s / (d - c));

    var position = (scrollPercent * ($horizontal.position().left + $horizontal.width()));

    $horizontal.css({
        'left': position
    });
});
```

```css
.section {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
    position: relative:
}

.boatFlex1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    background-color: green;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;

}

.boatFlex2 {
    width: 47%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #090080;
}

#horizontal {
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    background: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section">
</div>
<div id="boatFlex1" class="boatFlex1">
    <div id="boatFlex2" class="boatFlex2">
        <div id="horizontal">test</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section">
</div>
```